# Intersection of two families of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I got stuck while reading through some proof involving set operations. Define $P = \bigcup_{j \in A} S_j\cup (S_1 - \{x\})$ and $Q = \bigcup_{j \in B} S_j\cup (S_1 - \{y\})$, where $x,y \in S_1$ and $A,B \subseteq \{2,3,...,m\}$. Then
$$|P \cap Q| \geq \left| \bigcup_{j \in A \cap B} S_j \right|.$$
I started with $$|P \cap Q| \geq \left| \left( \bigcup_{j \in A}S_j \right) \cap \left( 
\bigcup_{j\in B} S_j \right)\right|$$
from the distributive property of set intersection. I don't know how to proceed from here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convince yourself that
$$\bigcup_{j\in A\cap B}S_j\subset\left(\bigcup_{j\in A}S_j\right)\cap \left(\bigcup_{j\in B}S_j\right)$$
(you can show this by looking at any element $z\in S_j$ for $j\in A\cap B$, and arguing why it must be an element of the right side.) Let the first of these be $T$ and the second be $U$. Then, it's enough to show
$$|T\cap U|\leq |P\cap Q|.$$
However, $P=T\cup(S_1-\{x\})$ and $Q=U\cup(S_2-\{y\})$. So, $T\subset P$ and $U\subset Q$. Can you see how to finish from here?

Comment: I understand the latter part of your answer, but I don't see why the equality you begin with holds

Comment: $$\bigcup_{j\in A\cap B}S_j=\left(\bigcup_{j\in A}S_j\right)\cap \left(\bigcup_{j\in B}S_j\right)$$

does not hold. Take $A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$ and $S_1=S_2=S$ be any nonempty set. Then, $$\bigcup_{j\in A}S_j=\bigcup_{j\in B}S_j=S$$ however, $A\cap B=\emptyset$ so $$\bigcup_{j\in A\cap B}S_j=\emptyset$$

Comment: @5xum Good point; I'd missed that subtlety. I've edited my answer to something I believe is correct.